# instance error from unreconized selector with @objc

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

when i run my aplication i get this error

Nick[66720:3658939] -[_SwiftValue function1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

i tried moving out of the class and it says
only protocol member can be there

```
import Cocoa

class mymainclass: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate{


var mytimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(function1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func applicationDockMenu(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSMenu? {
    return dockMenu
}



  @objc func function1(){
    print(“function1 test”)
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use **self** on the class level, this way it is not referring to your created class instance.

Instead, you can create the timer after your class instance is created.
Inside the class constructor, there **self** will be referring to what you are expecting

```
class Mymainclass: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate{
    var mytimer: Timer?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.mytimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(function1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func function1(){
        print("function1 test")
    }   
}
```

***Note:*** Class names start with Capital letter

Comment: when i use ur way, it starts the timer at the start of my application automaticly when i actualy want to start later via a function

Comment: That is correct. If you would like it to run at a different time, simply call it from a different place (Not from init) or make time interval longer

Comment: makes sense, its how i had done it originaly but i realy wanted to combine the specification of the timer in its main variable as seen in my example is there a way to do that at all?

Comment: Not sure for what purpose would it be good, is there a specific time you would like to to execute? As a class specification there is no option

Comment: just to simplify the code